# How do I solve my pyqt5 installation error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5

I am new to the world of python and I was hoping you could help with my PyQt5 installation troubles.
I tried installing pyqt5 on my ubuntu 18.04 machine  using the terminal.
I've tried every suggestion but I simply can't figure it out.

```
pip3 install --user pyqt5
```

I came across this error.

```
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python /home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpw7wu80bm:
    ERROR: Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/bin/qmake -query
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 64, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 197, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 67, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        config_settings)
      File "/home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 95, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 82, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 387, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 86, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 202, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 76, in apply_user_defaults
        self._get_qt_configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 431, in _get_qt_configuration
        for line in project.read_command_pipe([self.qmake, '-query']):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-giguc0l7/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 350, in read_command_pipe
        raise UserException("'{0}' failed returning {1}".format(cmd, rc))
    sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python /home/jcreigns/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpw7wu80bm" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-rqrr5o_m/pyqt5
```

Comment: It's a shame they closed this question. I have the exact error. The question that "already has answers" is outdated and useless.